# Reject with ICMP Code 3 Type 13

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I'm trying to reject packets with iptables with ICMP type 3 code 13, communication administratively prohibited.

Does anyone know a method of doing this? There doesn't seem to be an argument to --reject-with that generates these packets.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--reject-with icmp-admin-prohibited`

Using `icmp-admin-prohibited` with kernels that do not support it will result in a plain DROP instead of REJECT

Comment: Unfortunately that triggers a separate type and code, ICMP type 3, code 10.  Further research seems to indicate that iptables doesn't support this behavior.

Comment: Nevermind...this is the correct answer, thanks Teddy!

Comment: @Steve: You can delete comments, you know...